# How to override the View method and return Partial View from overridden View?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I have more than 200 controllers on an existing application. I would like to implement the partial behavior on each action so :

- If the request query contains `partial` key, I `return PartialView(model);`
- Otherwise, I `return View(model);`, which is the default behavior

Here is the override `View` method

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public override ViewResult View(object model)
    {
        if (Request.Query.ContainsKey("partial"))
        {
            // return PartialView(model); //cannot convert PartialViewResult to ViewResult 
        }
        return base.View(model);
    }
   //....
}
```

How to do I override the View method in order to return ViewResult or IActionResult, containing PartialViewResult  ? how to do this otherwise?

Comment: Why you don' t use an abstract base class ActionResult?

Comment: Honestly I didn't try to remove then `override` feature and replace `ViewResult` with `IActionResult` Thank you, I'll post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on @serge comment, I could remove the `override` keyword and replace with `new` implementation like this

```
public new IActionResult View(object model) {
  if (Request.Query.ContainsKey("partial")) {
    return base.PartialView(model); //cannot convert PartialViewResult to ViewResult
  }
  return base.View(model);
}
```

Now it works fine. thank you @Serge